# Making sfinae works for functions with deduced return type?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Consider the following code:

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// Preprocessor
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //



// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// Calls a function without arguments if it can be called
template <
    class F, 
    class... Args,
    class = decltype(std::declval<F>()())
>
decltype(auto) apply(F&& f)
{
    std::cout<<"apply(F&& f)"<<std::endl;
    return std::forward<F>(f)();
} 

// Calls a function with arguments if it can be called
template <
    class F, 
    class Arg,
    class... Args,
    class = decltype(std::declval<F>()(
        std::declval<Arg>(), std::declval<Args>()...
    ))
>
decltype(auto) apply(F&& f, Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout<<"apply(F&& f, Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)"<<std::endl;
    return std::forward<F>(f)(
        std::forward<Arg>(arg), 
        std::forward<Args>(args)...
    );
} 

// Does nothing if the function cannot be called with the given arguments
template <
    class F, 
    class... Args
>
void apply(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout<<"apply(F&& f, Args&&... args)"<<std::endl;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //



// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// Main function
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Initialization
    auto f = [](auto&& x) -> decltype(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x).capacity()) {
        return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x).capacity();
    };
    auto g = [](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x).capacity();
    };
    auto h = [](auto&& x) {
        return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x).capacity();
    };

    // Test
    apply(f, std::vector<double>());  // -> sfinae works
    apply(g, std::vector<double>());  // -> sfinae works
    apply(h, std::vector<double>());  // -> sfinae works
    apply(f, std::array<double, 1>());// -> sfinae works
    //apply(g, std::array<double, 1>()); -> sfinae fails, does not compile
    //apply(h, std::array<double, 1>()); -> sfinae fails, does not compile

    // Return
    return 0;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
```

The utility `apply`, applies a function to arguments when it can compile, otherwise it does nothing. The mechanism relies on sfinae. However, for function whose return type is deduced from the body, like `g` and `h` in the above example, sfinae fails. Would there be a smart way in C++14 to modify the `apply` utility so that it forces sfinae to kicks in even for functions whose return type is deduced from the body?

Note: I would like to make `g` and `h` work as `f`, meaning that the call of `apply` should call the `void` version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SFINAE can only catch substitution errors.

Some errors when calling a function cannot be substitution errors.  These include errors that happen when you parse the body of a function.

C++ explicitly chose to exclude these errors from triggering SFINAE and instead trigger hard errors to free compilers from having to compile bodies of arbitrary functions to determine if SFINAE occurs.  As SFINAE must be done during overload resolution, this makes the overload resolution code of a C++ compiler easier.

If you want your code to be SFINAE friendly, you cannot use lambdas like `g` or `h`.

Comment: What I don't quite understand is that I would expect the type system to parse the return statement to deduce the return type. But I guess this kicks in after sfinae. Is there no convoluted way to force it to kick in before sfinae?

Comment: @vince no.  Parsing bodies of functions resulting in errors generates "hard" errors at substitution time.  This was explicitly done to keep SFINAE somewhat bounded in scope.  If you want SFINAE support, the compatibility must be in the signature, not the body.

Comment: Thanks, make more sense. "keep SFINAE somewhat bounded in scope" => so I guess relaxing that could explode in very unexpected ways...

Answer (score 1):

Your SFINAE works just fine, as regards to `apply`.

As to why `f` works, it's because:

1. It's a template and
2. It fails already in the substitution phase.

This means it has SFINAE of it's own, and for `f` the 
default do-nothing is called (for `array`), as intended.

---

> Would there be a smart way in C++14 to modify the apply
>   utility so that it forces...

No, `apply` already does all it should.

As to why `g()` and `h()` does not work, they will produce
hard errors when you call them with something that does not
have `capacity`.
A utility function you (try to) apply *after* that can
not remove that hard error.
The only way to fix this is "double whammy" SFINAE,
like you do in `f()`

Comment: The OP wants the call to `apply` to compile but do nothing if the member function does not exist.