# Confusion with hard error in SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

With regards to the following code (https://wandbox.org/permlink/nhx4pheijpTF1ohf reproduced below for convenience)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace foo_name {
template <typename T>
void foo();
template <>
void foo<int>();

template <typename T>
struct c_size;
template <>
struct c_size<int> : public std::integral_constant<int, 1> {};
} // namespace foo_name

template <typename Type>
class Foo {
public:
    template <typename T>
    static decltype(auto) impl(T&& t) {
        using foo_name::foo;
        return foo(std::forward<T>(t));
    }
};

class Something {};

template <typename Type, typename T = std::decay_t<Type>>
using EnableIfHasFoo = std::void_t<
    decltype(Foo<T>::impl(std::declval<T>())),
    decltype(foo_name::c_size<Type>::value)>;

template <typename Type, typename = std::void_t<>>
class Test {};
template <typename Type>
class Test<Type, EnableIfHasFoo<Type>> {};

int main() {
    static_cast<void>(Test<Something>{});
}
```

The code above exits with an error because the instantiation of `Foo<T>::impl()` causes a hard error and is not usable in a SFINAE context.  But the strange thing here is that when you switch the order of things in the `void_t` in `EnableIfHasFoo` (to the following https://wandbox.org/permlink/at1KkeCraNwHGmUI), it will compile

```
template <typename Type, typename T = std::decay_t<Type>>
using EnableIfHasFoo = std::void_t<
    decltype(foo_name::c_size<Type>::value),
    decltype(Foo<T>::impl(std::declval<T>()))>;
```

Now the questions are

1. Why does the code initially not compile?  The instantiation of `Foo<T>::impl()` is in context of the substitution, so it should work?
2. Substituting `foo_name::foo(T)` in place of the first argument to `void_t` will make it compile (see https://wandbox.org/permlink/g3NaPFZxdUPBS7oj), why?  How does adding one extra layer of indirection make the situation different?
3. Why does the order in `void_t` make a difference, does the compiler short circuit the expressions within the type pack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) and 2) have the same answer; [SFINAE does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034729/making-sfinae-works-for-functions-with-deduced-return-type) with [return type deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396819/sfinae-with-c14-return-type-deduction?rq=1) since the body of a function is [not in immediate context](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#10):

> 10 - Return type deduction for a function template with a placeholder in its declared type occurs when the
>   definition is instantiated even if the function body contains a `return` statement with a non-type-dependent
>   operand. [ *Note:* Therefore, any use of a specialization of the function template will cause an implicit
>   instantiation. Any errors that arise from this instantiation are not in the immediate context of the function
>   type and can result in the program being ill-formed (17.8.2). *— end note* ]

3) is [a more interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368022/why-does-the-order-of-template-argument-substitution-matter); the short-circuiting is intentional, and is guaranteed by [[temp.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#7):

> 7 - [...] The substitution proceeds
>   **in lexical order** and stops when a condition that causes deduction to fail is encountered.

This short-circuiting works for gcc, clang and ICC, but unfortunately MSVC (as of CL 19 2017 RTW) gets it wrong, [for example](https://godbolt.org/g/aapu5i):

```
template<class T> auto f(T t) -> decltype(t.spork) { return t.spork; }
template<class T> auto g(T t) { return t.spork; }
int x(...);
template<class...> using V = void;
template<class T> auto x(T t) -> V<decltype(f(t)), decltype(g(t))> {}
int a = x(0);
```

Comment: Ah. Very interesting!  Before I accept this. I feel like i get the rules around "immediate context" wrong a lot. Could you link me to a resource or something where i can learn what exactly this immediate context is?

Comment: Also how why does this code compile when there is no extra layer if indirection. i.e. My second question. Is that because of return type deduction? If Foo::impl() had a specified return type. Would this code work?

Comment: @Curious https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260685/what-exactly-is-the-immediate-context-mentioned-in-the-c11-standard-for-whic is quite helpful, I think. If `Foo::impl()` has a specified return type, that return type is in the immediate context so is covered by SFINAE.

Comment: One last followup, why is it that when I supply the return type of `Foo::impl` in my code, it compiles?  Isn't `foo_name::foo` still out of the current context since it deduces return types?

Comment: @Curious it's not what it does (calculating a return type) that matters, its where it happens (in the function template declaration as opposed to the function template body). The function template instantiation is what makes the return type deduction occur outside the immediate context in your original case.

Comment: But even if i replace the body with a trailing return type. Isnt the return type going to be deduced in the body of foo_name::foo() anyway?

Comment: @Curious `foo_name::foo` is specified as `template <typename T> void foo();` so there's no need to instantiate it to find out its return type.

Comment: Ah, yes I got confused with another example I wrote before asking this question.  So if `foo_name::foo` had an `auto` return type it would trigger an error right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151529/discussion-between-ecatmur-and-curious).